# If statement Based on a selected row in a UIPickerView

Tags: arrays, swift, uipickerview

So i have an input page for the user to input a list of data. eg Paddock names (back Paddock, Front Paddock, etc) This then is stored for later use.

I then have a picker view on another page that displays this list of names. What i want is an if statement that when the user selects the first name in the list it will do (this...) else if the user selects the second name in the list it will do (this instead...) and so on for each name.

The problem I'm having is i don't know what the user is going input as the name of his paddock. so i can't say ,

```
if pickerview == "back paddock"
  do (this...)
else if pickerview == "Front Paddock" 
  do (this instead...)
```

Any ideas would be appreciated P.S I'm using Swift 3

Comment: Are you using an array to populate your pickerview?

Comment: yes, the data from the input page is saved as an array

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `UIPickerViewDelegate` to be able to respond to user selection. It has a method called `pickerViewDidSelectRowInComponent` which  gets called by the picker view when the selection changes. This is the appropriate place to implement your logic. Please [see the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipickerviewdelegate/1614371-pickerview) for further instructions.